# Jquery: How to add more code to list div/html tag

Tags: jquery

i have code div:

```
<div>content1</div>
<div>content2</div>
<div>content3</div>
<div>content4</div>
```

how to add code to end div 2

```
<div>content1</div>
<div>content2</div>
<div class="a">Add content</div>
<div>content3</div>
<div>content4</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `after()` in jquery

```
$("div:eq(1)").after('<div class="a">Add content</div>');
```

or `.insertAfter()`

```
$('<div class="a">Add content</div>').insertAfter("div:eq(1)");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XppqY/)

Comment: i'm chage `<div>` to `<article>` and add: `$("article:eq(2)").insertAfter('<div class="a">Add content</div>');` but not run, give me fix its. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use JQuery:

```
$("div:eq(1)").insertAfter('<div class="a">Add content</div>');
```

Else use

```
parentNode
```

Answer (score 0):

use the jQuery function: after()

```
$('div').eq(1).after('<div class="a">Add content</div>');
```